# How to create a plot for undermentioned data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, data-visualization, data-cleaning

I have this data (RDS format) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wHGVKYLv5fw_gJmlAiwuxHkbGj0H-zG6/view?usp=sharing - i hope you can download this file from this link. If you can't - let me know. My task is to visualize relation between **CO2 emissions (metric tons per capita)** and **Access to electricity (% of population)**. Here is what I came up with:

```
data <- readRDS("WDI.rds")
View(data)
new_data <- select(data, -Country.Name.x, -Country.Code, -Region, -IncomeGroup,
                   -Indicator.Code)
new_data <- filter(new_data,
                        Indicator.Name == c("Access to electricity (% of population)",
                                            "CO2 emissions (metric tons per capita)"))
new_data <- group_by(new_data, Indicator.Name)
View(new_data)
str(new_data)
```

I created new dataframe with only columns that I needed for a better overview, then sectioned CO2 and Access to electricity off - that's what I was able to do. My idea was to group years by Indicator.Name,
use tidyr (pivot_wider) but I honestly have a hard time even with visualizing it in my head - pretty odd, because the task itself is clear and understandable. I do not use R too often, know only a few packages and if I work on data like this usually I have columns "years" and "value" already. Here each year is a column. At the end I wanted to use ggplot2 to create a visualization (I don't think I will have problem here, I use this package quite often when I use R, my problem not knowing how to clean my data proper way).

Answer (score 0):

Your dataset is quite confusing and what you are trying to plot is not clear enough in order I'm able to give you my help on that part.

However, regarding what you are trying to do (selecting years and one categorical column to reshape it and be able to plot it), you can do it quickly using `dplyr` and `tidyr` as this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
data %>% filter(Indicator.Name %in% c("Access to electricity (% of population)",
                                        "CO2 emissions (metric tons per capita)")) %>% 
  select(Indicator.Name, starts_with("X")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Indicator.Name, names_to = "year", values_to = "value") %>%
  mutate(year = as.numeric(gsub("X","",year))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = value, group = Indicator.Name, color = Indicator.Name))+
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Again, the graph is not great because I think it could make more sense to have a second categorical variable (country or region) and represent either the mean or plot this as boxplot. But from my understanding, your question was about being able to extract some data from your dataframe and reshape them to be able to plot it.

So, does this answer your question ?